# Проверка логина регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Доброго времени суток.

Необходимо на Java проверить логин: он должен начинаться с латинской буквы, может состоять из латинских букв, цифр, точек, минуса, а заканчиваться буквой или цифрой.

```
"^[A-Za-z]{1}+([A-Za-z0-9-]{1,18})+([A-Za-z0-9]{1})$"
```

- не работает, HELP.

Comment: Была бы моя воля вообще бы убил regexp как чистой воды шаманство не имеющего отношения к программированию...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[A-Za-z]([.A-Za-z0-9-]{1,18})([A-Za-z0-9])$
```

Вы используете квантификатор '+' после квантификатора, указывающего точное кол-во символов данного символьного класса, что является лишним в обоих случаях.

Про точку вы совсем забыли.

Comment: Ваше регулярное выражение кстати неправильное

Вполне подойдёт логиин: "A--------------------B" :)

Дело в том, что "." в регулярном выражении - это любой символ, поэтому её нужно экранировать.

`^[A-Za-z]([\.A-Za-z0-9-]{1,18})([A-Za-z0-9])$`

А в Java так вообще:

`^[A-Za-z]([\\.A-Za-z0-9-]{1,18})([A-Za-z0-9])$`

Comment: Интерпретация символа "." зависит от места в регулярном выражении. В определении символьного класса точка - это просто точка.

Приведенный вами пример логина подходит под условия задачи.